# Extended WPF Toolkit is too verbose in Visual Studio output Window

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, xceed

Just added Extended WPF Toolkit [from Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Extended.Wpf.Toolkit/) and added the *AvalonDock* to my app.
It's really too verbose in the output window of Visual Studio :
[image]

Is there a way to reduce the verbosity of this lib ?

**EDIT :** in other words, an external library, used by my application, is polluting the Visual Studio output window, probably by doing some code like `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("...")` .

Is there a way to keep ONLY my own diagnostic messages in the output window ?

Comment: The Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.dll which is in the nuget package was probably built in DEBUG mode. You can try to download and build yourself the [source](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) in Release mode so the `Debug.WriteLine` won't be included.

Comment: @nemesv Thanks for reply. I hoped not to get there, to keep Nuget benefits. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) or follow suggestions on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271449/visual-studio-suppress-debug-output-per-dll).

Hope it helps.