# Filter what prints to the Console window in a .net Console App

Tags: .net, console-application, stdout

I have an app that uses some 3rd party dlls.  One of these is poluting my console output with messages like this:

> DEBUG: Logger was created successfully.. Priority: Low. Timestamp:2015-01-29 17:01:12Z.

**Is there a way to suppress or filter what actually is sent to the console window?**

NOTE: I don't have control of the code that is actually sending the Console.WriteLine for this.

Comment: Seems it may not be a simple task as mentioned here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271449/visual-studio-suppress-debug-output-per-dll)

Comment: This question has hundreds of thousands of duplicates at SO.  Everybody overlooking that they *do* have control.  Using the device that everybody has within reach: a telephone.  Nobody can make the call for you.